# How to fix VOBU Read Errors in k9copy?

Tags: 11.04, video, dvd, cd-ripping

I am trying to backup a few DVDs of mine. For this purpose, I looked at k9copy. When I start the process my terminal drowns in VOBU Read errors. -- And those are serious, as they are followed by four exclamation points ;)

Example output:

```
$ k9copy 
Disc in /dev/sr0 is a Video DVD
Disc in /dev/sr0 is a Video DVD
Disc in /dev/sr0 is a Video DVD
VOBU : 0 Read Error !!!!
VOBU : 52 Read Error !!!!
VOBU : 0 Read Error !!!!
VOBU : 85 Read Error !!!!
VOBU : 196 Read Error !!!!
VOBU : 316 Read Error !!!!
VOBU : 446 Read Error !!!!
VOBU : 654 Read Error !!!!
VOBU : 954 Read Error !!!!
```

Comment: Does the copy play? Those errors could just be caused by copy protection bad blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rookie's mistake. Failing to just play a DVD within vlc or smplayer I realized I was missing libdvdread4, so

`sudo apt-get install libdvdread4 && sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

fixed the problem.